# how to create checkbox check if value exist in database in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($college_id as $fetch) 
    {
        $facility=explode(",",$fetch['facilities']);
        foreach ($facility as $key) 
        {
            $facilities = $key;
        }
    }
?>

<input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Gym' <?php if(in_array("Gym",$facilities)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Gym
<input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Boys Hostel' <?php if(in_array("Boys Hostel",$facilities)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Boys Hostel
<input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Girls Hostel' <?php if(in_array("Girls Hostel",$facilities)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Girls Hostel
<input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Scholarship' <?php if(in_array("Scholarship",$facilities)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Scholarship
```

In this code I have multiple checkbox and value are exist in database. Now, I want to check checkbox if value exist in database. So, How can I do this ? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code.

```
<?php
    $college_id = array('facilities'=> array('Gym', 'Boys Hostel'));
?>

 <input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Gym' <?php if(in_array("Gym",$college_id['facilities'])) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Gym
 <input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Boys Hostel' <?php if(in_array("Boys Hostel",$college_id['facilities'])) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Boys Hostel
<input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Girls Hostel' <?php if(in_array("Girls Hostel",$college_id['facilities'])) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Girls Hostel
<input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Scholarship' <?php if(in_array("Scholarship",$college_id['facilities'])) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Scholarship
```

Gym and Boys Hostel checkbox will be checked.

Cheers!!

Comment: what if i also want the id in value attribute with the checked or uncheckd checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think it works.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]"  value="Gym" <?= 
  if(in_array("Gym",$college_id['facilities']) == "Gym") ? "checked" : "" ?>>Gym
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you declared `$facilities = $key;` it means $facilities is not array. the fix is like this:

```
<?php
$facilities = array();
foreach ($college_id as $fetch) 
{
    $facility=explode(",",$fetch['facilities']);
    foreach ($facility as $key) 
    {
        $facilities[] = $key;
    }
}
?>

<input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Gym' <?php if(in_array("Gym",$facilities)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Gym
<input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Boys Hostel' <?php if(in_array("Boys Hostel",$facilities)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Boys Hostel
<input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Girls Hostel' <?php if(in_array("Girls Hostel",$facilities)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Girls Hostel
<input type='checkbox'  name='facilities[]' value='Scholarship' <?php if(in_array("Scholarship",$facilities)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>> &nbsp; Scholarship
```